# Can I use VARCHAR(32) for md5() values?

Tags: php, mysql, md5

Can I use a field of length 32 and of type VARCHAR in a MySQL database for md5() values?

Comment: why are you using MD5?

Comment: You can, but I'm not sure you'd want to.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use md5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3897434/1291428

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security

Comment: All those links say is, it's insecure for some uses. There are still other, valid uses for md5.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since md5 always produces fixed length result, better use CHAR(32)

Comment: thank you, what is the difference between char and varchar then?

Comment: They are stored and retrieved in a different way. Read more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: you can't have char and varchar mixed in one table - so, doesn't matter. varchar is okay.

Comment: @YourCommonSense `varchar` data loaded to memory with full blown size. I mean if a column is `varchar(128)` and only 32 characters(1 byte chars) are stored in it; when loaded to memory it occupies 128 bytes. Is that true?

Comment: and isn't `varchar(32)` has overhead over `char(32)` in case of `MD5`?

Comment: I'd argue for making the field definitions match what the fields will contain. If the value will never deviate from 32 characters, make it a char(32). If it can be up to 254 (e.g. for an email address) then make it a varchar(254). Give the database the best information that you have on a field and let it handle optimizing as best as it can. Relational databases have been around for a long time and have several optimizations built into them. Even if the current version lacks an optimization here, future versions can. Don't make things harder by lying to the database about your data.

Comment: be aware that char 32 will take 128 bytes in unicode

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `CHAR(32)` with `latin1` charset, or `BINARY(16)` if you want to save more spaces.

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
    ...
    md5 CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' NOT NULL
    ...
```

MySQL uses `utf8mb4` as default charset since 5.7, and `CHAR(32)` with `utf8mb4` takes 128 bytes, worse than `VARCHAR(32)`.

Comment: utf8/utf8mb4 is a vary length encoding. Use CHAR(32) for md5 will only take 32 bytes instead of 128 bytes. 

It's only matter while you index this field. Few people index a md5 field I thought.

Comment: @petertc `Use CHAR(32) for md5 will only take 32 bytes` I don't think so. If MySQL really treat utf8/utf8mb4 CHAR(32) as vary length, and if I replaced one alphabetic or number char with a non-ascii char like `ü`, the length may changed from 32 bytes to 33 bytes, isn't it? But how MySQL store length info for that column?

Comment: The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store.  <= not bytes. CHAR/VARCHAR(32) may takes 32~128 bytes (exclude length prefix)